# In AWS - Subdomain with SSL Certificate doesn't work in RESTful call

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, subdomain

I have an AWS Amplify instance to launch a REACT app I have.  It also has an SSL Certificate, so I can access the app on the browser by entering:
https://myreactapp.com  (not my real app url, just an example)

I have a web servlet running on an Elastic Beanstalk instance that doesn't have SSL certificate, and my REACT app interfaces to it with this code snippet I have:

```
    var myObject = {
        data1: this.state.data1,
        data2: this.state.data2
    }


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://<my-backend-webservices-app>.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/doSomething', // works only from React app when running on local machine (http://localhost:3000), not from https url
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
        data: myObject,
        success: function(response) {
          console.log('success -- ' + response);  
        },
        function(errMsg) {
            alert('Major Error');
        }
    });
```

This code works fine and I get a response from my **my-backend-webservices-app** when I run my React App locally on my machine.  Since when I use it locally the react app is on http://localhost:3000 (notice its not an https) and its talking to the Elastic Beanstalk instance which is also on http.

But when I run my React app from the AWS Amplify with SSL certificate it complains that a RESTFul request from HTTPS can't communicate to http url.  Here's the error from the browser:

> jquery.js:8676 Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://master.<.....>.amplify<...>.com/' was loaded over HTTPS,
>   but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/doSomething'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

So my thought to resolve this is to add a SSL Certificate to my ElasticBeanStalk instance.  So first I created a subdomain **services.myreactapp.com** where the main domain is **myreactapp.com** I then assigned my ElasticBeanstalk instance (where my my-backend-webservices-app is) to that **services.myreactapp.com** subdomain.

I then went to the **Certificate Manager** service page of aws and requested a public certificate that is assigned to the services.myreactapp.com subdomain.

So now I updated the URL of the code snippet above to have https instead of http:

```
        url: 'https://<my-backend-webservices-app>.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/doSomething',
```

But now whenever my React app from https makes the request to the back end servlet, it just hangs.

Any thoughts at what I'm missing?

Comment: From where are you managing your domain name ?

Comment: I got the main domain using AWS Route 53 services

Comment: I have posted a solution in my ans, Previously I have used CNAME to point to my backend service and then used that URL as backend URL. Let me know if you face any issue after that !

Comment: My backend application was hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and I had ELB configured for that. I was looking for ways to create a subdomain for backend API calls and enable secured traffic. My search ended here. Just for anyone exploring later, following might help:
0. I didn't create a separate hosting zone for my subdomain. Refer to point 1.
1. Add routing for your subdomain to AWS ELB: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html
2. Configure your ELB for https: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things to highlight here.

#### about ACM issued Certificates

- First of all, if you request a certificate from the certificate manager, it won't be applied to any of your applications automatically, you need to apply the certificate to your applications.

#### using ACM issued Certificate with Elasticbeanstalk

- You can apply the certificate obtained from ACM to the elasticbeanstalk only if you are using a load balancer. In this case You can simply select your certificate from your elasticbeanstalk configuration page.

  **Reference:**
  configure ssl for elasticbeanstalk load balancer - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html

#### If you are not using load balancer (Single instance)

- You have to apply the certificate to the application running inside elasticbeanstalk or its proxy (for e.g nginx). You can use `.ebextensions` to achieve this.

  **Reference:**

  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-nodejs.html

  https://medium.com/@hzburki.hzb/configure-ssl-certificate-elastic-beanstalk-single-instance-a2846211851b

#### Pointing `subdomain.example.com` to elasticbeanstalk's DNS name

- Once you have enabled SSL on your loadbalancer or configured your single instance to serve your application over ssl, you can create an `A` record to point `services.myreactapp.com` to your elasticbeanstalk dns name. make sure to to select Alias `Yes` when you create the `A` record.

#### Using the new dns name from your frontend app

finally you can use `subdomain.mydomain.com` from your frontend app instead of the elasticbeanstalk dns name.

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: I got it to work using the link you posted https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html though there was one thing I had to change in my configuration that wasn't explicity discussed in that link that I'll post below.  But thanks though as that link was what I needed!

Comment: Thank you. Just for my knowledge, which part is not covered.

Comment: I should better clarify, the aws link covered everything I needed.  Just at first the "modify" button wasn't there for the "Configuration -> Load Balancer" panel in my elastic beanstalk ec2 instance.  I had to change the environment type of my instance before that appeared ( I talk a little about that below in a separate answer/post below).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it working thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59540740/4722577 @Arun K's response above.

The link I used was:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html

In short, through the **Configuration -> Load Balancer -> Modify** button I had to configure my Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance to use Load Balancing with a listener.  Then associate the existing SSL Certificate I have with this listener.

However, when I tried to do that at first that **modify** button didn't exist (notice it says that Load balancing is not available in my configuration).

[image]

Part of the aws link mentions this if you get that message:

> Note If the Load balancer configuration category doesn't have a Modify
>   button, your environment doesn't have a load balancer.

The way forward is to select **Configuration -> Capacity -> Modify** on the screenshot above, then select "Load Balanced" instead of "Single Instance" in the **Environment Type** drop down box.

[image]

After you apply those changes, a "modify" button is enabled for **Configuration -> Load Balancer** sub panel.  I continued the steps in the AWS link above and am now able to communicate from my https://myreactapp.com to my **my-backend-webservices-app**

Answer (score 0):

Go to AWS route 53, In DNS management create a CNAM DNS record which points to your beanstalk url, like -

```
services.myreactapp.com -> xyz.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

then use `services.myreactapp.com` in your react app as url. Also before doing that make sure that you are able to access your backend at `https://services.myreactapp.com`, you can check you health API if any to test that. Note - This might take sometime to get services.myreactapp.com to come in action.